# How to fix an inconsistant Dialogflow account?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I did tests with Actions on Google and I've been redirected to Dialogflow to create my Intents.

Unfortunately, I had to delete my project on Actions on Google and now I cannot create Intents anymore because I'm still on the same Dialogflow account and I cannot delete it as I get logout each time I try to remove an Agent.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access you Dialogflow agent then

- you can export your agent into a collection of JSON files
- build a new agent and import/restore the old agent using exported JSON files
- once done, you can integrate it to your new Actions-on-Google project and test your Google Assistant app

[Export/Import the Agent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents#export_and_import)

Comment: I cannot Export my agent like I cannot remove it. I get redirected on the "Sign in with" page :/

Comment: Contact dialogflow support